# How to add validation on custom textbox field on checkout page Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I added custom field in shipping method division on checkout page.

But i want to add validation on it.

So, how to add validations **required** and **numeric** to that field.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail. how you added input field on checkout page .

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="" action="" id="" method="" data-hasrequired="* Required Fields">
    <fieldset class="">
        <div class="">
            <label class="" for="field1"><span>Field 1 (using data-validate)</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                        <input name="field1" id="field1" title="Field 1" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{'validate-number':true}" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope so this may help you,

there is some rule in Magento to validate input field that rules the state in "data-validate" attribute in field tag. You can validate the field for may restriction using this attribute. search for other validation rules, there are about 99 rules